# Implementing a circuit that returns $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ with equal probability

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, circuit-construction, optimization, random-quantum-circuit

Using Python how can I implement a quantum circuit that returns $|01\rangle$ or $|10\rangle$ using only $CX$, $RX$ and $RY$ gates, starting with random parametric gates as parameters and optimizing it using gradient descent or other optimization algorithm?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far to answer this question?

Comment: I have used IBM Quantum Experience and have used an Rx gate (using pi/2 as theta) on qubit 1

Answer (score 2):

One potential combo is $ RY(\theta)$ on qubit 1, $CX$ from qubit 1 to qubit 2, then $RX(\pi)$ on qubit 2. This would be the following transformation:

$$ |0\rangle |0\rangle \mapsto (\cos \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle + \sin \frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle)|0\rangle \mapsto \cos \frac{\theta}{2} |00 \rangle + \sin \frac{\theta}{2} |11\rangle \mapsto \cos \frac{\theta}{2} |01 \rangle + \sin \frac{\theta}{2} |10\rangle $$

This could be implemented in Python with QISKit/Q#/etc.

(Matrices for $RX$, $RY$: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.rx / https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.ry)